# Connecting to MYSQL database error (UWP C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, uwp

I writing UWP app for windows 10 desktop

I trying to connect to DB on server

My code:

```
 using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Database= milano_app2;Data Source=IP_OF_SERVER;User Id=USERNAME;Password=;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            connection.Open();


            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE demotable(salary int,surname varchar(255))", connection);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            MySqlCommand addCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO demotable (salary,surname) VALUES (1234,'Вейдер')", connection);
            addCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

But when I launch app i have this error
[image]

I think problem in encoding of BD?

How I can make it UTF-8?

Thank's for help.

Comment: How about adding "CharSet=utf8" to connection string ?

Comment: Database= milano_app2;Data Source=144.76.133.122;User Id=milano_app2u;Password=xm1dzkQC;SslMode=None; CharSet=utf8

Comment: You mean like this?@x...

Comment: All ok. Thanks @x...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add CharSet=utf8 to connection string :

```
"Database= milano_app2;Data Source=IP_OF_SERVER;User Id=USERNAME;Password=;SslMode=None;CharSet=utf8;"
```